# perl parsing using sax

Tags: perl

I would like to write a xml parsing script in Perl that prints all the `firstname` values from the following xml file using [XML::SAX](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSAX) module.

```xml
<employees>
    <employee>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <lastname>Doe</lastname>
        <age>gg</age>
        <department>Operations</department>
        <amount Ccy="EUR">100</amount>
        </employee>
        <employee>
        <firstname>Larry</firstname>
        <lastname>Page</lastname>
        <age>45</age>
        <department>Accounts</department>
        <amount Ccy="EUR">200</amount>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <firstname>Harry</firstname>
        <lastname>Potter</lastname> 
        <age>50</age>
        <department>Human Resources</department>
        <amount Ccy="EUR">300</amount>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Can anyone help me with sample script?
I am a new to Perl.

Comment: i have tried this but dont know how to print the node values.      use XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
use XML::SAX::Writer;
my $writer = XML::SAX::Writer->new;

my $parser = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser(Handler => $writer);

eval { $parser->parse_file('sample.xml') };
die "can't parse Lizzie's stock file: $@"   if $@;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using `XML::SAX`. I've used `XML::SAX::PurePerl`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
use XML::SAX::PurePerl;

my $characters;
my @firstnames;

my $factory = new XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
#Let's see which handlers we have available
#print Dumper $factory;
my $handler = new XML::SAX::PurePerl;
my $parser = $factory->parser(
              Handler => $handler,
              Methods => {
                  characters => sub {
                      $characters = shift->{Data};
                  },
                  end_element => sub {
                      push @firstnames, $characters if shift->{LocalName} eq 'firstname';
                  }
              }
          );

$parser->parse_uri("sample.xml");
print Dumper \@firstnames;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'John',
          'Larry',
          'Harry'
        ];
```

I use `$characters` to hold character data, and push its contents onto `@firstnames` whenever I see a closing firstname tag.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I have one more question. How to handle duplicate element names in SAX? Following is my xml file.

Comment: <employees>
 <employee>
  <name>John</name>
        <age>gg</age>
  <department>Operations</department>
  <amount Ccy="EUR">100</amount>
  <company>
   <name> xyz </name>
  </company>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <name>Larry</name>
  <lastname>Page</lastname>
        <age>45</age>
  <department>Accounts</department>
  <amount Ccy="EUR">200</amount>
  <company>
   <name> abc </name>
  </company>
 </employee>
</employees>

Comment: My question is how to access the element employees->employee -> company->name? The reason I am asking this is because there is one more 'name' element at employees->employee->name which i want to skip. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any reason to stick with XML::Sax; If not then probably you can look for some other XML parsers in Perl (XML::Twig, XML::LibXML, XML::LibXMLReader, XML::Simple) and many more.

Here is a sample code to retrieve the firstname using XML::Twig.

```
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new ();
$twig->parsefile ('sample.xml');

my @firstname = map { $_->text } $twig->findnodes ('//firstname');
```